# How can I get JSON from an API into a view of my Angular app?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object that is returning at

```
localhost:9000/api/
```

and I'd like that JSON data to populate a view at

```
localhost:9000/#/query
```

I've got a route

```
.when('/query', {
  templateUrl: 'views/query.html',
  controller: 'QueryCtrl'
})
```

and a controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
    $scope.queries = Query.query();
  }]);
```

and the view:

```
<h1>Queries</h1>

<ul ng-repeat="query in queries">
  <li>{{query}}</li>
</ul>
```

it seems that either "queries" is empty though, or else the view is just not properly connected to the controller.

The app.js also has this factory:

```
app.factory('Query', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api', null, {
    'update': { method:'PUT' }
  }); 
}]);
```

The JSON object itself looks like this:

```
[{"tablename":"acc_logs"},{"tablename":"accounts"},{"tablename":"cat_logs"},{"tablename":"err_logs"},{"tablename":"exp_logs"},{"tablename":"pp_logs"},{"tablename":"sec_logs"},{"tablename":"stl_logs"},{"tablename":"tim_logs"},{"tablename":"tom_logs"},{"tablename":"usage_logs"}]
```

I can see the JSON string at `/api`, but when I go to `/#/query`, it is just an empty list.

How can I connect these? What mistake have I made?

**EDIT: Thanks for all the help everyone. I forgot to add my controller javascript in index.html. Rookie mistake, took an hour to fix.**

Comment: Change this line: `$scope.query = Query.query();` to `$scope.queries = Query.query();`, as you are using `ng-repeat` over `queries`.

Comment: Whoops, looks like that was one of the problems. However I'm still getting an empty view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing that you are calling the Query object that seems to be unavailable, try:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Group) {
    $scope.query = Group.query();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this does help. I not longer have a Group object because I renamed it Query, guess I missed one. However, I changed it to   .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
    $scope.queries = Query.query();
and it's still broken

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed in the comment, you should change `$scope.query = Query.query();` to `$scope.queries = Query.query();`, as you are using `ng-repeat` over `queries`.

However, there are another error. You must change

```
app.factory('Query', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api', null, {
    'update': { method:'PUT' }
  }); 
}]);
```

to

```
app.factory('Query', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/query', null, {
    'update': { method:'PUT' }
  }); 
}]);
```

When you call `Query.query()` you are requesting a HTTP GET to `/api`, while you want to request to `/api/query`.

Comment: I have my doubts about this because there is no json being returned to /api/query. The results I want are in /api. Sure enough, I still have an empty view

Comment: @johncorser Are you sure? In the first line of your question you said that the json object is returned at `localhost:9000/api/query`. Anyways, please verify what is the URL being called in the console.

Comment: The results are at localhost:9000/api. I have edited the original post now. Sorry for any confusion